# Does R automatically remove '.' from data.frame column names?

Tags: r

does d1$patient....age = d1$patient....age ?

I'm guessing these is a simple concept that causes this behaviour.
Is this a reliable behaviour that is predictable?
ie: if I name a data.frame column a...b can I always references it by $a ?

The example provided in the source doesn't explain what I'm seeing in R.

from http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/SvetlanaEdenRFiles/regExprTalk.pdf

```
d1 = data.frame(id...of....patient = c(1, 2), patient....age = c(3, 4))
d1$patient....age
#[1] 3 4
d1$patient
#[1] 3 4
d1$age
#NULL
d1$id...of....patient
#[1] 1 2
d1$id
#[1] 1 2
d1$id...of
#[1] 1 2
names(id)
#NULL
names(d1)
#[1] "id...of....patient" "patient....age"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R's `$` operator accepts any unambiguous prefix of a column name as referring to that column. It has nothing to do with `.`s.

For example, try:

```
d1$id...of....patient
# [1] 1 2
d1$id...of....pati
# [1] 1 2
d1$id...o
# [1] 1 2
```

This is true whether or not there are dots in the column name: `mtcars$disp`, `mtcars$dis`, and `mtcars$di` all return the `disp` column of the `mtcars` dataset. (However, `mtcars$d` returns `NULL`, as both the `disp` and `drat` columns start with `d`).